# How can an XML schema require elements to be sorted by attribute?

Tags: xml, xsd

Suppose I have an XML file that looks like this:

```
<Transactions>
<Transaction OrderID="5"> ... </Transaction>
<Transaction OrderID="6"> ... </Transaction>
<Transaction OrderID="11"> ... </Transaction>
<Transaction OrderID="7"> ... </Transaction>
</Transactions>
```

Using XML schema, is it possible to indicate that Order #11 is not in the correct sequence?
Each Transaction element individually passes validation, but the OrderID should be in increasing order.

And, a related question:     Can a validation rule indicate whether or not numbers can be skipped?
For example, there is no transaction #8,9, or 10.

Answer (score 1):

If your validator supports XSD 1.1, you can use xs:assert to deny certain attribute values like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
           xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" 
           elementFormDefault="qualified" 
           attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
           vc:minVersion="1.1">
   <xs:element name="Transactions">
      <xs:complexType>
         <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Transaction" maxOccurs="unbounded">
               <xs:complexType mixed="true">
                   <xs:attribute name="OrderID" type="xs:integer"/>
                   <xs:assert test="empty(index-of((8,9,10),@OrderID))"/>
               </xs:complexType>                                
            </xs:element>
         </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
   </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

This should answer your second question.

As for your first question, I don't think order validation is possible. You can, however, use XSLT to sort the XML document.

----- added the answer to the first question -----

Thank you, Michael Kay. Well...here is the answer to your first question.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="Transactions">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Transaction" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:complexType mixed="true">
                        <xs:attribute name="OrderID" type="xs:integer"/>
                        <xs:assert test="empty(index-of((8,9,10),@OrderID))"/>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:assert test="every $x in Transaction satisfies 
                             (empty($x/preceding-sibling::*) or 
                             ($x/@OrderID gt $x/preceding-sibling::*[1]/@OrderID))"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Yes, order validation is possible. For example `<xs:assert test="every $x in * satisfies not($x/@att gt $x/preceding-sibling::*[1]/@att)"/>`

Comment: Thanks Chong Lip Phang.      Honestly, I don't understand your answer well enough to know if it solves my issue or not.     When you wrote   <xs:assert test="empty(index-of((8,9,10),@OrderID))"/>   presumably the 8,9,10 refer to specific values of OrderID?         The file I am working on has about 30K transactions in it.      Any method that works for me would need to work without reference to specific values for OrderID.       The second <xs:assert test... looks like a generic answer.     Are BOTH needed?

Comment: Yes, <xs:assert test="empty(index-of((8,9,10),@OrderID))"/> would cause the validation to fail if the value of OrderID is 8,9 or 10. If the XML data is a lot, then you probably need a rule to match a specific pattern. The validation will still pass if you omit this assertion rule and OrderID skips 8,9 or 10.

Comment: The second <xs:assert...> would cause the validation to fail if the values of OrderID are not in ascending order. So there are really two assertions here. You can omit both, use one, or use both. It really depends on what you wish to validate.